# Py.Test getting remaining test case count

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to get the test cases that are yet to be executed with Py.Test (in a py.test setup fixture with function scope or in pytest_exception_interact) .

When a test case is failed, I am setting a global flag in my conftest to indicate the test failure and reset the application to a default state in pytest_exception_interact and in the function setup of next function ,I validate this flag to run a set of pre-conditions before executing the tests. 
Now , I do not want to run the actions i am peforming when the last test case fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the information of total tests in a module with the argument node (node.parent._collected ), but I could not find a way to check if the tests are already executed or not . Right now , all I am doing is check the index of current test in this list and see how many are still in the queue to be executed .

```
def pytest_exception_interact(node, call, report):
    pass
```

If anybody, has a better solution kindly let me know.

Answer (score 0):

"pytest_exception_interact" is only called when exceptions are raised.

You can use use:

```
def pytest_collection_finish(session):
    total_tests_number = len(session.items)
```